Is it possible to use only integers for all positioning and sizing?
I'm quite annoyed by Visio losing positioning and sizing precision. I setup page properties to use points measurement units, I setup the grid to be fixed and have minimum spacing 1 point, I setup the layout and routing spacing to be in points. Generally speaking, I went through most or all settings and ensured that I have points everywhere. My thinking is that if I do that Visio at least won't need to do any conversion between inches, it was normally the unit before and points. So, to my best understanding everything is in points. I, also, ensured the strongest snapping to grid.
Even though, when I draw, let's say a rectangle and position it at 10, 10 points and make its size 100, 50 points and then simply start moving it around, very quickly I end up with a position expressed with a floating point, let's say like 145.75489, 745.24. This is what want to avoid. I already set the measurement unit points which is small enough to adhere all positioning and sizing to it. Is there any way to tell Visio to use only integers and if in the result of any calculation it is not integer, to round to the nearest integer?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Perhaps a macro to resize objects to the same size might help a bit, as at https://groups.google.com/g/microsoft.public.visio.general/c/auvdGDrvp8o

Please try set fixed grid size!

View -> Show -> Ruler&Grid
Grid spacing (horizontal and vertical): Fixed
Minimal spacing: 1 mm
Also can helps
View -> Show -> Visual aids
Set Dynamic grid and Ruler subdivisions are unchecked.
When you draw rectangle please make it with odd size. Like 30x20 mm, not 30x15 mm.
